# Joint PDF of Z and W

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider X
and Y
as two independent random variables with X,Y∼U(0,1)
. Let W=X-Y
and Z=X+Y
. Determine the Joint Probability Density Function of X and Y, and find P(Z>3W)
.

Using the Jacobian method, I obtained f(z,w) = 1/2. However, I believe I made a mistake with the intervals. If 0 < x,y < 1, then we have -1 < w < 1 and 0 < z < 2. However, upon integrating it, I obtained 2 instead of 1. What went wrong? I think it's the range of w and attempted to graph it, but I found it quite challenging. Regarding P(Z > 3W), do I simply need to integrate f(z) from 3w to 2? (Assuming the limits for z are correct).

Comment: The key word is independence and $Z > 3W \iff X+Y > 3X - 3Y \iff 2Y > X$ It should be easy to compute this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Half of your  $-1 < w < 1$ and $0 < z < 2$ range (a square of area $4$) has zero joint density, such as near $(0.75, 1.75)$.

You in fact have $\max(-w,w) < z < \min(w+2,-w+2)$, which you could write as $|w| < z < 2-|w|$ if you prefer.  This is a rotated square of area $2$; within this rotated square you are correct that the density is constant $\frac12$.

You would find the total probability is $$\int_{w=-1}^{0}\int_{z=-w}^{2+w} f(w,z)\, dz\, dw + \int_{w=0}^1\int_{z=w}^{2-w} f(w,z)\, dz\, dw=1$$
as you might hope, and then adjust the integration limits to find $\mathbb P(Z>3W)$.

Alternatively, since you know the joint distribution of $W$ and $Z$ is uniform on its support of the rotated square, you could find the proportion of the area above/left of the red line in the diagram geometrically.

[image: Z against W chart]

Comment: That's pretty clear. Just checking, I adjusted the integration limits and had P(Z>3W)=1, it's possible but also questionable, is it correct?
.

Comment: @Stats... 1 is not correct after adjusting the integration limits - not all of the rotated square is above the red line.  You should have $\int_{w=-1}^{0}\int_{z=-w}^{2+w} f(w,z)\, dz\, dw  $ $+ \int_{w=0}^{1/2}\int_{z=3w}^{2-w} f(w,z)\, dz\, dw$